# Timer in java with Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, timer

I want to print this line:

```
System.out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
```

every second. How to do it?

```
public class Hilo implements Runnable{    

    Thread t;
    String nombre;
    public  Hilo() {
         t = new Thread(this,"Hilo1");
         t.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want help at least format your code...

Answer (score 3):

Use a `java.util.Timer` object.

> A facility for threads to schedule tasks for future execution in a background thread. Tasks may be scheduled for one-time execution, or for repeated execution at regular intervals.

```
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
    }
}, 0, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it

```
ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

ses.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
    }
}, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

ses.shutdown();
```

Differences between `java.util.timer`  and `ScheduledExecutorService`

1. **ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor** are not sensitive to changes in the system clock but **Timer** is.
2. **Timer** has only one execution thread, so long-running task can delay other tasks.
   **ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor** can be configured with any number of threads

Answer (score -1):

By using below code you can print that want after every second

```
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
                System.out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
               }
              }, 0, 1000);

    }
```

Comment: @AnubianNoob but this is not a wrong way u can also implement same thing with using Thread.sleep() i just write code as per OP's demand

Comment: yup i tried it and found that it is a better way ..Thanks @AnubianNoob i just update my answer